# How to make an event handler like Timer.Tick

Tags: c#, .net, events

How to make an **event handler** which is fired at particular interval of time like `System.Windows.Form.Timer` has `Tick` event which is fired at given interval of time.

I want to make somthing like in below example.

**Example:**

```
void myClass_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        /*
          I want this event to be occur every 10 sec or 20 sec depends upon
          value of myClass.Interval.

          I don't want to use Timer class which check at every Tick and 
          fire my event when desired value is met.

        */
}
```

**Update:**

```
class myClass
{
    public int Interval { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Tick; // I want this event handler to work as timer.Tick

    protected virtual void OnTick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Tick != null)
        {
            Tick(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? I don't understand your question. Doesn't SWF's timer work for you?

Comment: @Paul, I am making a class which have some properties and events I want to make an event-handler like Timer.Tick which is fired at particular interval of time.

Comment: @Javed: Why don't you use SWF Timer then?

Comment: I don't think Javeds problem is UI related. He just wants to periodically fired events in one of his classes.

Comment: @ChrisWue, Yes, you are right.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why don't you want to use the `Timer` class inside of your class?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the one of the `Timer` classes.

If you're not using WinForms, you should use `System.Timers.Timer`.

It's possible to do it without a timer using threading, but it's very much not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do exactly the `System.Threading.Timer` might be a good choice.

**Update**: Here you can find a comparison of the three timer classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: That is a Silverlight/Windows Phone 7 OS specific class